# What is the definition of $\{0,1\}^I$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $I=[0,1]$, and $\Omega=\{0,1\}^I$.  what is the definition of $\Omega$

Comment: It is the set of all functions from $I$ to $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: You are right. the mean of $\Omega$

Answer (score 2):

For those that aim to be precise with their set-theoretical notations and terminology, there is a difference between the fundamental notion of *map* and the fundamental notion of *family*.

Given an arbitrary family $A$ of sets indexed by set $I$, the cartesian product $\displaystyle\prod_{i \in I}A_i$ is by definition the set of all families $x$ indexed by $I$ and such that at each index $i \in I$ the component $x_i \in A_i$ is subject to this condition, of being an element of $A_i$. In the particular case when all the factors $A_i, i \in I$ of such a product were equal to one and the same set $B$ one simplifies the general notation $\displaystyle\prod_{i \in I}B$ down to the more convenient $B^I$, which is by definition the set of all *families* (not maps) $x$ of elements of $B$ indexed by $I$.

The relation between a map from $I$ to $B$ and a family of elements of $B$ indexed by $I$ is very close, as by definition any map from $I$ to $B$ is a triplet of the form $(I, F, B)$, where $F \subseteq I \times B$ is a *functional* relation fully defined on the whole of $I$ (in other words $F$ is what Bourbaki calls a *graphic* such that $(x, y), (x, z) \in F$ entails $y=z$ and such that the first projection of $F$ is $I$ itself), object which is nothing else than a *family* of elements of $B$ indexed by $I$. In other words -- somewhat loosely speaking -- a map also consists of its domain of definition and codomain, structurally encoding these in a triplet as exhibited above, whereas a family certainly knows nothing about any codomain and is defined differently, as a mathematical object.

With these amendments in mind, $\{0, 1\}^{[0, 1]}$ is the set of all families $\lambda$ indexed by the interval $[0, 1]$ and capable of taking only the two values $\{0, 1\}$ (i.e. at every index $t \in [0, 1]$ it is either the case that $\lambda_t=0$ or $\lambda_t=1$).

Answer (score 1):

It means, as suggested by Kavi, the set of functions from $I$ to {0,1}. Note this is a general set-theoretical notation, when we have any two sets $X$ and $Y$, then the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ is denoted $Y^{X}$.

The main reason for this notation is about cardinality, indeed the cardinality of the set of functions $Y^{X}$, denoted $|Y^{X}|$ is exactly $|Y|^{|X|}$.